# Exchanging Files Client-Server architecture JAVA

Tags: java, android, networking, client-server

I am trying to send an image from the android phone, process it on the server side, and then get it back to the phone. I have been able to send the file from the phone to the server but then it seems that the server cannot send the image using the same socket. I am using bufferedinputstream and bufferedoutputsteram. is it possible or would i need 2 different ports? code is in java.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have a 2-way-communication by using one socket connection.

In easy words: the server's outputstream is the client's inputstream and vice versa.